# Estimate limit of sequence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-request, integer-sequence

The following sequence may have two limits, depending on the parity of $n$ as [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3698990/156150):

$$a_n=(1-\frac{1}{2!})^{(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!})^{\ldots^{(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!})}}}$$

I have tried to create Mathematica code to evaluate these limits taking the parity of $n$  into consideration, but I didn't succed.

I have never come across this example before.  I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What have you tried? Include your attempts as starting points.

Comment: I am not replicating the claimed values. Anyway, does this help? `In[20]:= Quiet[
 RSolveValue[{a[n + 1] == a[n]^((n + 1)/(n + 2)*1/(n + 1)!), 
   a[1] == 1/2}, a[n], n]]

Out[20]= 2^(-((2 Gamma[1 + n])/BarnesG[3 + n]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has to be careful here, because you can't just nest `Power`, so I've folded it in reverse:

```
(* note that FullSimplify[1/Factorial[i]-1/Factorial[i+1]] == i/Gamma[2 + i] 
   which is i/Factorial[1 + i] for integer i *)
sequence = Table[Fold[#2^#1 &, Table[i/(i + 1)!, {i, n, 1, -1}]], {n, 1, 15}];
ListLinePlot[N /@ sequence, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
N[sequence[[-1]]]
N[sequence[[-2]]]
```

[image: factorial sequence periodic plot]

The two limits are 0.548774... and 0.779543...
I couldn't find either number in the OEIS.